# Quadratic extensions - understanding

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

If $[L:K]=2$ then $L/K$ is a quadratic extension.

- Can we think of a quadratic extension as $L=K(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is anything not in $K$(be it algebraic or transcendental)?
- This makes $L$ a $2$-dimensional $K$-vectorspace with basis $\{1,\alpha\}$ by Kroneckers theorem, and means any irreducible $f(x)\in K[x]$ with root $\alpha$ in $L$ has all of its roots(it splits). Is its second root $-\alpha$?
- Then in $\text{char} 0$ quadratic extensions are normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) A quadratic extension of $K$ must be the splitting field of a quadratic polynomial; by the quadratic formula, we see that $L=K(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \notin K, \alpha^2 \in K$. It cannot be the case that $\alpha$ is transcendental over $K$, because in that case $K(\alpha)$ is, by definition, infinite.

2) (A note: Your notation in this question could use improvement, as you're using $\alpha$ in two different way.)  No. Consider the quadratic extension $L=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. The polynomial $f(x)=x^2 - 2x - 1$ has roots $1 \pm \sqrt{2}$.

3) Yes. Even better, any quadratic extension is Galois.

Comment: Follow up on $1)$. Finite extension $\implies$ algebraic extension?

Comment: Yes, every finite extension is algebraic. If $L/K$ has degree $n$, then for any element $\alpha \in L - K$ the set $\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^n \}$ must be linearly dependent, which shows that $\alpha$ satisfies a polynomial, i.e. $\alpha$ is algebraic.

Comment: Thank you, that is now clear.